# Windows Event Viewer giving cryptic string values for its attributes in XML mode

Tags: c#, event-viewer, windows-defender

I am trying to log windows defender events from Event Viewer using C# .net framework. When I try to capture Event data attribute values via reading XML it gives me weird string values for some attributes like **Origin Name, Execution Name, Type Name, Action Name**.

[image]

And actual Values of these attributes in General view is displayed proper as follow.

[image]

Here is Code snippet I am using to xml data :

```
        private static void GetRecordsInfo()
    {
        //string channel = "Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational";
        string _channel = @"C:\Users\patilp\Desktop\DefenderLogs.evtx";
        string query = "Event/System[ TimeCreated[@SystemTime > '2020-07-15T19:08:30.895832100Z' and @SystemTime < '2020-07-15T20:21:30.895832100Z']" +
            " and ((Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4) and (EventID = 1006 or EventID = 1007 or EventID = 1008 or EventID = 1009 or " +
            "EventID = 1010 or EventID = 1011 or EventID = 1012 or EventID = 1015 or EventID = 1116 or EventID = 1117 or EventID = 1118 or EventID = 1119) and Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender'])]";

        EventLogQuery eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery(_channel, PathType.FilePath, query);
        EventLogReader eventLogReader = new EventLogReader(eventLogQuery);
        EventRecord record = eventLogReader.ReadEvent();
        if (record == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No data found");
            return;
        }
        var _currentEvent = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        _currentEvent["ProviderName"] = record.ProviderName;
        _currentEvent["ProviderEventGuid"] = record.ProviderId;
        _currentEvent["Channel"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(_channel) ? String.Empty : _channel;

        _currentEvent["EventID"] = Convert.ToString(record.Id);
        _currentEvent["Level"] = Convert.ToString(record.Level);

        string rawXml = record.ToXml();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(rawXml);
        Dictionary<string, string> _EventData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        XmlNodeList xmlnodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Data");

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlnodeList)
        {
            string text = node.InnerText;
            string attr = node.Attributes["Name"]?.InnerText;
            _EventData.Add(attr, text);
        }

        _currentEvent["ThreatID"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Threat ID") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Threat ID"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Threat ID"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["ThreatName"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Threat Name") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Threat Name"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Threat Name"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["Severity"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Severity ID") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Severity ID"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Severity ID"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["Category"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Category Name") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Category Name"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Category Name"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["Path"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Path") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Path"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Path"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["DetectionOrigin"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Origin Name") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Detection ID"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Detection ID"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["DetectionType"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Type ID") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Threat ID"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Threat ID"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["DetectionSource"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Source Name") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Detection User"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Detection User"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["Status"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Status Description") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Status Description"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Status Description"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["ProcessName"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Process Name") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Process Name"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Process Name"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["Action"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Action Name") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Action Name"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Action Name"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["ErrorCode"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Error Code") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Error Code"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Error Code"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["ErrorDescription"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Error Description") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Error Description"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Error Description"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["SignatureVersion"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Security intelligence Version") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Security intelligence Version"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Security intelligence Version"] : "NA";
        _currentEvent["EngineVersion"] = _EventData.ContainsKey("Engine Version") ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_EventData["Engine Version"]) ? "NA" : _EventData["Engine Version"] : "NA";

        foreach (var item in _currentEvent)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}  :   {1}",item.Key,item.Value);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to obtain proper string values for mentioned attributes..?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue.

I've managed to find out, that some codes like that can be found in file `msobj.dll`: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/3242

Using this code found online: https://gist.github.com/mattifestation/43248b6f59d1dd67d4f57318a9a7e565
I've managed to extract every code in that file, but it does not seem to be right in this case. For example %%812 returns `'Trusted To Authenticate For Delegation' - Disabled`.

So I assume that codes for Defender events are in some other dll... But which ?

Edit:
This source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/541bad5d-19eb-4de5-8ef7-1b144f0b6113/translate-xxxx-values-in-events?forum=w7itprosecurity

claims that `msobj.dll` contains complete key-values entries EventViewer can show you. At least in Windows XP. Seems that something must have changed in Windows 10, because I only have `msobjs.dll`.

EDIT2: I have found an answer!

This is a solution from the book by Stuart Squibb "PowerShell and Windows Event Logs"

Apparently those attributes, or placeholders, reside in the Message Table of the dll:
`C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpEvMsg.dll`

This is how to find which dll Event is using (note that different event providers have different dll): 
`$Provider = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.ProviderMetadata 'Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender'`
`$provider | Select-Object *`

Then using code written by the author I've extracted the codes:

https://github.com/wightsci/MessageTableReader

`Add-Type -Path "C:\MessageTableReader.cs"`
`$messageTable = New-Object MessageTableReader.Reader`
`$messageTable.GetMessageList('C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpEvMsg.dll')`

Enjoy ;-)